# Question in regards to POA of selfish routing networks

Tags: game-theory

I need help to understand this sentence. This make little sense to me.

> Suppose a set C contains all of the constant functions. Then the
> Pigou-like networks that define α(C) use only functions from C, and
> α(C) is a lower bound on the worst-case POA of selfish routing
> networks with cost functions in C
>
> As long as C contains at least one function c with c(0) > 0, the Pigou
> bound is a lower bound on the POA of selfish routing networks with
> cost functions in C. The reason is that, under this weaker assumption,
> Pigou-like networks can be simulated by slightly more complex networks
> with cost functions only in C